# Vue: axios: 404 response not found: while the page exists

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a `GetAnimal.vue` file that contains this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form v-on:submit.prevent="getAnimal()">
            <textarea v-model = "animal"
                name = "animal" type="animal" id = "animal"
                placeholder="Enter your animal here">
            </textarea>

            <button class = "custom-button dark-button"
                type="submit">Get animal</button>
        </form>


        <button class="custom-button" v-on:click = "goTo('/viewanimal')">
            View animal
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                name: 'defaultAnimal',
                animal: {
                    name: 'Cat',
                    furColor: 'red',
                    population: '10000',
                    isExtinct: false,
                    isDomesticated: true
                }

            }
        },
        methods: {
            goTo: function(path)  {
                // alert(path);
                this.$router.push({ path });
            },
            getAnimal: function () {
                alert("animals");
                this.info = {
                    "fur-color": "yellow", "population": '51000', "isExtinct":
                        false, "isDomesticated": true
                };

                axios({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/getanimal',
                    data: {
                        animal: this.animal
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

inside **router.js** it is mapped like this:

```
{
            path: "/getanimal",
            component: () => import('./views/GetAnimal.vue')
}
```

When I go to `http://localhost:8080/getanimal` in browser I see this:

[image]

*(has some inherited styles from the `App.vue`)*

When I click the `Get Animal` button it displays the `animal` alert and then I see this in console:

[image]

Why can't I send an `axios` request to the very page I'm currently at? Why do I get the 404 error and how should I fix it?

Comment: error 404, usually means your url path is incorrect. Check your spelling and make sure the entire url matches what you are calling. Also matters if api is running on http:// or https:// because ports are different.

Comment: @AlejandroH It should be correct: I copypaste it from the address bar of the very `getanimal` page I'm always at

Comment: `https` seems to have worked - I get `err_ssl_protocol_error ` now. It doesn't result in 404 however so it must have found it. However I had to hardcode it like this: `url: 'https://localhost:8080/getanimal'`, while `url: '/getanimal` would automatically direct to `http` instead of `https`. Is there a way to make the relative path work?

Comment: I am not sure what `err_ssl_protocol_error` is exactly. What backend are you using? to me it seems like its supposed to be `/api/getanimal` but I could be wrong. It would help if we could know more about your backend code.

Comment: @AlejandroH I'll sort the `err_ssl_protocol_error` on my own, I think. Or in another question. Here I just want to sort the 404 error: I still get it if I go to `/getanimal`. it appears if I just use the relative path `/getanimal` instead of explicit `https://localhost:8080/getanimal` - because the `/getanimal` goes to `http` instead of `https`. Is there a way to get `/getanimal` work instead of failing with `404`?

Comment: what status if you open it in browser ?

Comment: As I said in my question I can open that page just fine in the browser. I can send `axios.get('https://localhost:8080/getanimal`)` just fine as well. However `axios.get('/getanimal')` would go to `http://localhost:8080/getanimal` instead of `https://localhost:8080/getanimal` which results in `404` I've described in the question.

Comment: It would help if we can see how you have your backend routes configured. You might just be getting an error with https:// because your backend was not configured for that path. If you can share your configuration, it would help

Comment: you could set redirect url on backend

Comment: I don't have *any* backend right now. `localhost:8080` is where `vue / npm / nodejs` is

Comment: i'm confused,if your vue pages running at `http`,how could you get it from `https`?

Comment: No idea. But: browser: `http://localhost:8080/getanimal` works fine. Axios: `http://localhost:8080/getanimal` - 404 error, axios: `https://localhost:8080/getanimal` works fine, axios `/getanimal` goes to `http://localhost:8080/getanimal` - 404 error. That's just the way it is. All I'm looking for is for a way to make axios: `/getanimal` work

Comment: what http headers when you open it by browser , and http status

Comment: `app.js` and `chunk.js`   are the same as it? maybe you refresh it by`ctrl+f5`

Comment: The same as what? I've refreshed the page plenty of times?

Comment: could show your all codes?

Comment: You can't load a Vue page from within your Vue app via AJAX like that. Resolving vue-router URLs requires that the JS runs. All you will get is the contents of your `index.html` page and if you're using `history` mode without the appropriate server-side configurations, that would explain your 404 error

Comment: I literally just realized he was not using a backend until now. Port 8080 is just vue.js.

Comment: @Alejandro H me too